# Uploading an Image using jQuery Ajax plugin not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using [Malsup's jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery("input[name=file]").change(function(e){
            if( browserType == "MSIE" ){
                jQuery("#start_campaign").ajaxForm({
                    target: '.imgPreview',  
                    url: host+"/forms/campaign-image-upload.php?action=ajaxUploadImage",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        console.log(2);
                    },
                    success: function(responseText,statusText,xhr,$form) {
                        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
                        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
                    }
                }).submit();
            } else {
                readURL(this);
            }   
        });
    });
```

It's running on the `beforeSend` function but after that it has this kind of error:

```
SCRIPT3: Member not found.
 
jquery.form.js, line 349 character 5
LOG: [jquery.form] state = complete
```

This is line 349:
[image]

What's the problem with this code? I've been searching on the internet and found no answer.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answered this one by looking on this url: http://peroijanet.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/script3-member-not-found/

It seems the error is about having multiple submit buttons on your page with the same `name="submit"`
Make sure you only have one submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />`

Gosh this saved my Day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Same error is coming in my project also becuse i have trigger the a tag to file upload control.

If you have trigger the file upload control to other element like div or a etc if yes then please remove the trigger to file upload control and simple display file upload control in IE  then upload image it will work perfectly.

Please try this.

Sorry for my bad english